# How to read telnet sessions with python

Tags: python, telnetlib

Aloha, i'm creating a teamspeakbot and want to write and read to a telnet session created with a TeamSpeak3 server

```
import telnetlib
tn = telnetlib.Telnet('localhost', 10011, 10)
tn.read_all()
```

What i'm expecting:

```
Connected to localhost
Escape character is '^]'.
TS3
Welcome to the TeamSpeak 3 ServerQuery interface, type "help" for a li...
```

But instead i get a time out after the 10 seconds:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 325, in read_all
    self.fill_rawq()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 516, in fill_rawq
    buf = self.sock.recv(50)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

How can i read **all** stuff the telnet connection tells me and later write some stuff to it (like the login proces and submit commands and get the response ...)

## The Solution is

`tn.read_very_eager()`

My code now looks like this:

```
import telnetlib, time
tn = telnetlib.Telnet('localhost', 10011, 10)
tn.write('help\n')
time.sleep(0.05)
print(tn.read_very_eager())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read_all() blocks until EOF is reached*, or until your timeout is reached. While I've not used telnetlib much, I have assumed it's for the sort of service which displays something then closes the connection.

How do you get on with code like:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet('localhost', 10011, 10)
tn.read_some()
```

*https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_all